# Copy/paste OmniFocus actions for iOS on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, omnifocus

Is there any way to copy/paste actions in OmniFocus for iOS on the iPhone?

If I recall correctly, there used to be a beta feature you could enable in the settings which allowed you to press and hold on an action to show the "copy" option, but it's no longer there in the latest version.

Is there any other way to duplicate actions in OmniFocus without having to use another client?

Answer (score 1):

If you click on an action or a project in the latest version of OmniFocus Universal for iOS, it provides a system share sheet that has a copy extension, which allows you to copy it as Taskpaper. That can then be pasted back into the application or you can use an application such as [workflow](https://workflow.is) to make a new project or action based on your copied data, which may be slightly more convenient.